# UITextView is scrolling even when contentSize is CGSizeZero when isEditable and isSelectable

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, uiscrollviewdelegate, uitextviewdelegate

I am editing in `UITextView`, and do not want it to scroll, but respond to touch events. Even after I have set the contentSize to CGSizeZero, it gets reset to a different frame. Can someone help with this?

Comment: you have to disable scrolling of uitextview

Comment: Tried it! By disabling scroll of UITextview touch events will get disabled @Birendra

Comment: when I set scrollEnabled = NO itself the touch is not recognized for that UITextView @Birendra